# How to get access to child package object in Angular

Tags: angular, this, viewchild

I used a package in **app.component.html**

```
    <app-my-test2 *ngIf="data" #MyTest2Component></app-my-test2>
```

here's **app-my-test2** package. (with ngPackager)

and used **in **app.component.ts****

```
@ViewChild('MyTest2Component', {static: true}) myTest2Component: MyTest2Component;
```

befor, convert **app-my-test2** to package, all work correctly and i access **app-my-test2** "this", but
after convert **app-my-test2** to package, "this" returned undefind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my *ngIf. The *ngIf directive was killing my controls component so I couldn't reference it.

The issue as previously mentioned is the ngIf which is causing the view to be undefined. The answer is to use ViewChildren instead of ViewChild. I had similar issue where I didn't want a grid to be shown until all the reference data had been loaded.

```
 @ViewChildren("MyTest2Component") public myTest2Component: QueryList<MyTest2Component>


public ngAfterViewInit() {

    this.myTest2Component.changes.subscribe((comps: QueryList <MyTest2Component>) =>
    {
        console.log(comps.first) ;
    });

}
```

[document](https://www.xspdf.com/resolution/50353977.html)